# SwiftUI : TabBar app running on iPad missing tabs that's on iPhone

Tags: swiftui

I'm working on a TabBar iPhone app (in SwiftUI, using a TabView) that set to allow running on an iPad.

On the iPhone, my TabBar has the 3 tabs, everything works fine.
On the iPhone, even though the first tab's view is being displayed, but only the second and third tab's are in the TabBar.  If I tap on the second or third tab, I am able to tap back in the "area" of the first tab and select it.

Any help to getting all the tabs to display on the iPad would be appreciated.

iPhone..

[image]

iPad..

[image]

```
    var body: some View {

        NavigationView {

            TabView(selection: $tabSelection) {
                QuestionnairesView(viewModel: questionnairesViewModel)
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Questions", systemImage: "person.fill.questionmark")
                }
                .tag(Tabs.tab1)

                TranscriptsView(viewModel: transcriptsViewModel)
                 .tabItem {
                     Label("Answers", systemImage: "quote.bubble.fill")
                }
                .tag(Tabs.tab2)

                AccountView()
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Settings", systemImage: "gearshape.fill")
                }
                .tag(Tabs.tab3)

            } // TabView
            .navigationBarTitle(returnNaviBarTitle(tabSelection: self.tabSelection))

        } // NavigationView

        // } //TabView
    }//Struct
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the exception to the rule that you place your `NavigationView` at the top of your hierarchy. A `TabView` does not play well inside of a `NavigationView`. Instead, place the, now, `NavigationViews` inside of each of your tabbed views and remove it from this view.

```
var body: some View {
    TabView(selection: $tabSelection) {
        Text("Tab 1")
            .tabItem {
                Label("Questions", systemImage: "person.fill.questionmark")
            }
            .tag(Tabs.tab1)
        
        Text("Tab 2")
            .tabItem {
                Label("Answers", systemImage: "quote.bubble.fill")
            }
            .tag(Tabs.tab2)
        
        Text("Tab 3")
            .tabItem {
                Label("Settings", systemImage: "gearshape.fill")
            }
            .tag(Tabs.tab3)
        
    } // TabView
}//body
```

Comment: First, thank you for the answer.  The reason why I placed the TabView in the NavigationView is that on that first tab's view (QuestionnairesView) I'm loading a chat interface using a NavigationLink.  And in that chat interface, I don't want to show the TabBar.  So the approach you suggested was the first approach I took.. but the TabBar is present on the chat interface on the child view.  Do you know another way to hide the TabBar?

Comment: Once you are in the `TebView` you are in it. The only suggestion I would have is to roll your own `TabView` that does what you want. Obviously, that brings with it navigation challenges in the UI. Most chat apps just leave the tab bar in the view.